# How does one identify the left-right adjustment screw on the lead door of a set of bifold doors?

Tags: doors

(Sorry for lengthy exposition of background: I don't really have a sense of which details are relevant and which can be safely omitted.)

I have a set of exterior bifold doors, on which I only ever use the lead door, effectively as a swing door; the remaining doors remain closed and with their locking mechanism engaged all the time.

Recently, when I attempt to close the lead door, the multipoint latch mechanism will not engage; when the door is in the closed position, I encounter insurmountable mechanical resistance on  attempting to raise the handle to engage the mechanism (when the door is in the open position, the handle raises and lowers and the bolts extend and retract without difficulty).

A Google search turned up very-similarly-worded adjustment instructions from various door manufacturers (e.g. [here](https://www.climadoor.co.uk/external-bifold-doors/article/how-to-adjust-external-bifold-doors)), from which I learned that my next move should be to try adjusting a hex-key-operated screw on the lead door's lower hinge in order to move the lead door from left to right.  The first hex-key-operated screw I found was tiny (about 2mm diameter and 3mm long), and aligned in the hinge's radial direction, about halfway along the length of the hinge.  I proceeded to try adjusting this screw alternately anticlockwise and clockwise, through gradually increasing numbers of turns (i.e. 2.5 turns anticlockwise, then 5 turns clockwise, then 7.5 turns anticlockwise...).  None of these operations improved the operation of the latch mechanism, and indeed it may have got slightly worse (in the sense that the insurmountable resistance arises earlier in the process of trying to raise the handle).

On my last set of anticlockwise turns, the screw reached the end of its travel and fell out of the hinge.  After several attempts, I've been able to put it back in, and I'm reasonably sure I don't have it cross-threaded (screw head looks parallel to local hinge surface on visual inspection, and I used the turn-backwards-a-little-while-under-axial-load-first trick); however, I now find that, long before the screw gets back to its original position, turning clockwise requires so much torque that I'm in serious danger of rounding the hexagonal socket on the screw head (indeed, I may have already filleted the corners of the hexagon somewhat).

After this, I noticed that there are actually some other hex-key-operated screws on the hinge: one of similar size to the one I've been adjusting, and also aligned in the hinge's radial direction, but near the top of the hinge; and one larger one aligned in the hinge's axial direction.

Hence, my main question is: how do I tell which screw I should have been turning to achieve the left-right adjustment of the door, please?  My secondary question is: what can (or should) I do about the screw that I now can't return to its original position?

Thanks very much.

As per @FreeMan's suggestion, here are some photos to illustrate this:

The full set of bifold doors:

[image: The full set of bifold doors]

The lead door:

[image: The lead door]

The hinge on which I attempted adjustment, viewed from the side:

[image: Hinge viewed from side]

The hinge on which I attempted adjustment, viewed from above:

[image: Hinge from top]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se] where we believe a picture is worth 1000 words (if not more). Please [edit] your post to include (simply drag the pics into the text edit box, the site will take care of uploading, hosting & embedding them for you) clear, focused pictures of the doors and screws you're working with. One nice overview (maybe include an arrow to point at the detail area), then detailed pics.

Comment: @FreeMan Good thinking; I'll get onto it.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but those are good pics, well described. I'm sure _someone_ will be able to help you soon.

Comment: Have you inspected each of the multipoint latches?  It sounds like maybe one has deformed.  Maybe post a picture of the each side of one multi point latch.

Comment: comment moved from newer question… Isn't the latch-plate adjustable? Or is it the top & bottom bolts that aren't shooting home [which should also be free-floating]? If you can't tell, spray them with WD 40, then put sheets of paper where they're supposed to land & attempt to close it. You should be able to figure out from the oil markings & creases where it's not fitting. Additionally, if you don't know which way the hinge adjusters push, wedge under the door & see which way lessens pressure on the wedge. However, if the door closes fully yet won't latch, move the latch-plates not the door.

Comment: @Tetsujin The door closes all the way, but springs open again as soon as I take my hand off the door frame.  Does that count as "closes fully"?

Comment: Did it do that before you started adjusting the hinges? Sounds like the hinge is now under tension, leaving you with the original issue plus a new one.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, it did spring open before I started adjusting the hinges, but perhaps not quite as strongly as it does now.  I got my spirit level out, and the lead door is sloping downwards towards its free end, whereas the frame is true, so I suspect moving the latch plate alone won't really fix the problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't think my eyesight was up to seeing the location of a little spot of WD40 (and in any case, I'm a super-strict vegetarian and the formula for WD40 contains a little bit of meat-derived fat), so I used Tipp-Ex instead.  All three bolts are striking 2 or 3 millimetres too low to get into the holes they're supposed to get into.

Comment: A further datum... I managed to get the screw that I'd tried to adjust to somewhere with good enough lighting to inspect it closely.  I _had_ damaged the head of the screw, but not in the way I'd thought: in fact, I'd swung the door shut (probably several times) while the screw was protruding slightly from the surface of the hinge, leading to the screw head striking the door frame in such a way as to put an enormous (for the size of screw) radial load on the screw head, so not only is the socket no longer a regular hexagon, the outer surface of the screw head is no longer circular.

Comment: I eventually called in a professional to adjust the door.  What he did certainly involved adjusting the screw that I've labelled "axial hex screw", and its equivalent on the uppermost hinge; but I don't think that's _all_ he did.  Either way, the door now opens and closes correctly.