# Location of manufacturer name on bifold doors

Tags: doors

I asked a [previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/216155/how-does-one-identify-the-left-right-adjustment-screw-on-the-lead-door-of-a-set) on here about the adjustment of bifold doors.  Since that didn't produce a resolution, I guess my next port of call is to ask the manufacturer.  That leads to my next question: where, on the set of bifold doors pictured in the previous question, am I likely to find the manufacturer's name, please?

The full set of bifold doors:

[image: The full set of bifold doors]

The lead door:

[image: The lead door]

The hinge on which I attempted adjustment, viewed from the side:

[image: Hinge viewed from side]

The hinge on which I attempted adjustment, viewed from above:

[image: Hinge from top]

Comment: @PhilippNagel Many thanks for transferring the photos across from the old question when I was too lazy to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If it's identified, it's likely to be on the top or bottom, or on the outer edges (that face in toward the closet when the door is open). It's possible that there would be a sticker or stamp of some sort that would be visible on the inside of the closet.

You may need to clear out some closet space and close yourself in with a flashlight to find it.

Well, it seems this isn't a closet (the pics weren't there when I first wrote the answer). However, the labeling is still most likely going to be on one of the door edges. It *might* be on the top or bottom, but that makes it really hard to find, so I'd guess that's not going to be it. It may not be on the "lead door" that is open in the pics, so opening the other door(s) may be necessary to find the sticker.

Comment: These are bifold patio doors, not on a closet. But the answer is probably still correct.

Comment: That is, well... the pics weren't there when I wrote up the answer and I didn't see the need to refer to the original post to write this up, so, in my defense. Well... I guess you're right @PhilippNagel

Comment: These appear to be double-pane windows. In the Milgard doors and windows in my house (aluminum frames, installed 2008), each panel is labeled between the two panes, on the inside of the vertical frames at the top.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Oo... There is some text there, but I'll have to wait for daylight (which is about 9 hours away here in the UK) to read it.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks.  I'd already looked on the free edge of the lead door, but not the harder-to-reach edges.  Again, I'll get onto it when it's daylight.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Yes, the text in that location does include a manufacturer name: "Glass Systems", although it's not entirely clear yet whether they made the complete bifold door system, or whether they just made three sealed double-glazed units and some third party added hinges and a locking mechanism...?